# PHP json_encode produces wrong JSON results. Why?

Tags: php, json

I am working on an application where i am generating JSON using PHP. My code is here.

```
$arrayItem = array_slice($data, $start, $max);
$jsonArray = array();
$jsonArray['total'] = count($arrayItem);
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i ++) {



     // Listomatic requires the "total" field to show/hide the "Show More" button

    // The following is sample data (in this case Powerball numbers) that you want to display

        $item = array(
            'id' => $arrayItem[$i]['id'],
            'title' => $arrayItem[$i]['title'],
            'featured_image' => $arrayItem[$i]['featured_image'],
            'audio_file' => $arrayItem[$i]['audio_file'],
            'youtube_id' => $arrayItem[$i]['youtube_id'],
            'open_par' => $arrayItem[$i]['open_par'],
            'category' => $arrayItem[$i]['category']);

        $list_array[] =  array('item' =>$item);

}

$jsonArray['items'] = $list_array;


header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

It produces the following JSON. I am not sure why the zeros are being added.

```
{
    "total": 10,
    "items": [
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "234",
                "title": {
                    "0": "Indulged in any Good Vices Lately?"
                },
                "featured_image": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
                },
                "audio_file": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/234_Indulge_in_any_good_vices_lately_12_15_02.mp3"
                },
                "youtube_id": {},
                "open_par": {},
                "category": {
                    "0": "Social Issues"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "233",
                "title": {
                    "0": "Do You Use the Spirit of a Sound Mind?"
                },
                "featured_image": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
                },
                "audio_file": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/233_Do_you_use_the_spirit_of_a_sound_mind_12_08_02.mp3"
                },
                "youtube_id": {},
                "open_par": {},
                "category": {
                    "0": "Parable"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "232",
                "title": {
                    "0": "What Does it Mean to be Thankful?"
                },
                "featured_image": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
                },
                "audio_file": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/232_What_does_it_mean_to_be_thankful_12_01_02.mp3"
                },
                "youtube_id": {},
                "open_par": {},
                "category": {
                    "0": "Inspiration"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "226",
                "title": {
                    "0": "Who is Jesus?"
                },
                "featured_image": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
                },
                "audio_file": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net"
                },
                "youtube_id": {},
                "open_par": {},
                "category": {
                    "0": "Doctrine"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "216",
                "title": {
                    "0": "Does God Really Torture People in Hellfire?"
                },
                "featured_image": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
                },
                "audio_file": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/216_Does_God_really_torture_Hellfire.mp3"
                },
                "youtube_id": {},
                "open_par": {},
                "category": {
                    "0": "Doctrine"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "192",
                "title": {
                    "0": "Why Don’t You Ever Listen to Me?"
                },
                "featured_image": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
                },
                "audio_file": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/192_Why_dont_you_ever_listen_to_me_02_10_02.mp3"
                },
                "youtube_id": {},
                "open_par": {},
                "category": {
                    "0": "Character"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "188",
                "title": {
                    "0": "Who Ends Up in the “Lake of Fire?”"
                },
                "featured_image": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
                },
                "audio_file": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/188_Who_ends_up_in_the_lake_of_fire.mp3"
                },
                "youtube_id": {},
                "open_par": {},
                "category": {
                    "0": "Doctrine"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "156",
                "title": {
                    "0": "Is Jesus Really God? (Parts III & IV)"
                },
                "featured_image": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
                },
                "audio_file": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2001mp3/156_Is_Jesus_really_God.mp3"
                },
                "youtube_id": {},
                "open_par": {},
                "category": {
                    "0": "Doctrine"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "155",
                "title": {
                    "0": "Is Jesus Really God? (Parts I & II)"
                },
                "featured_image": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
                },
                "audio_file": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2001mp3/155_Is_Jesus_really_God.mp3"
                },
                "youtube_id": {},
                "open_par": {},
                "category": {
                    "0": "Doctrine"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "124",
                "title": {
                    "0": "Did God Really Create the World in 6 Days?"
                },
                "featured_image": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
                },
                "audio_file": {
                    "0": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2000mp3/124_Did_God_create_the_world_in_6_days_10_22_00.mp3"
                },
                "youtube_id": {},
                "open_par": {},
                "category": {
                    "0": "Doctrine"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

While I need the following JSON to be output.

```
{
    "total": 10,
    "items": [
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "234",
                "title":"Indulged in any Good Vices Lately?",
                "featured_image": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg",

                "audio_file": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/234_Indulge_in_any_good_vices_lately_12_15_02.mp3",

                "youtube_id": "http://youtube.com/",
                "open_par": "",
                "category": "Social Issues"

            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "233",
                "title":"Do You Use the Spirit of a Sound Mind?",

                "featured_image": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg",

                "audio_file": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/233_Do_you_use_the_spirit_of_a_sound_mind_12_08_02.mp3",

                "youtube_id": "http://youtube.com/",
                "open_par": "",
                "category": "Parable"

            }
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "232",
                "title": "What Does it Mean to be Thankful?",

                "featured_image": "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg",

                "audio_file": "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/232_What_does_it_mean_to_be_thankful_12_01_02.mp3",

                "youtube_id": "http://youtube.com/v",
                "open_par": "",
                "category": "Inspiration"

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Forget about the blank values I just need the JSON structure. Please suggest whats wrong in my code. Thanks

Edit. My arrayItem var_dump is following.

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "234"
    ["title"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3306 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(34) "Indulged in any Good Vices Lately?"
    }
    ["featured_image"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3319 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(86) "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
    }
    ["audio_file"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3314 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(94) "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/234_Indulge_in_any_good_vices_lately_12_15_02.mp3"
    }
    ["youtube_id"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3315 (0) {
    }
    ["open_par"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3310 (0) {
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3323 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "Social Issues"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "233"
    ["title"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3312 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(38) "Do You Use the Spirit of a Sound Mind?"
    }
    ["featured_image"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3325 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(86) "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
    }
    ["audio_file"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3320 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(99) "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/233_Do_you_use_the_spirit_of_a_sound_mind_12_08_02.mp3"
    }
    ["youtube_id"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3321 (0) {
    }
    ["open_par"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3316 (0) {
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3329 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Parable"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "232"
    ["title"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3318 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(33) "What Does it Mean to be Thankful?"
    }
    ["featured_image"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3331 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(86) "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
    }
    ["audio_file"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3326 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(94) "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/232_What_does_it_mean_to_be_thankful_12_01_02.mp3"
    }
    ["youtube_id"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3327 (0) {
    }
    ["open_par"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3322 (0) {
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3335 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "Inspiration"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "226"
    ["title"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3324 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "Who is Jesus?"
    }
    ["featured_image"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3337 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(86) "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
    }
    ["audio_file"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3332 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(33) "http://www.christianquestions.net"
    }
    ["youtube_id"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3333 (0) {
    }
    ["open_par"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3328 (0) {
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3341 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "Doctrine"
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "216"
    ["title"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3330 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(43) "Does God Really Torture People in Hellfire?"
    }
    ["featured_image"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3343 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(86) "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
    }
    ["audio_file"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3338 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(85) "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/216_Does_God_really_torture_Hellfire.mp3"
    }
    ["youtube_id"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3339 (0) {
    }
    ["open_par"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3334 (0) {
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3347 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "Doctrine"
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "192"
    ["title"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3336 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(34) "Why Don’t You Ever Listen to Me?"
    }
    ["featured_image"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3349 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(86) "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
    }
    ["audio_file"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3344 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(92) "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/192_Why_dont_you_ever_listen_to_me_02_10_02.mp3"
    }
    ["youtube_id"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3345 (0) {
    }
    ["open_par"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3340 (0) {
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3353 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Character"
    }
  }
  [6]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "188"
    ["title"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3342 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(38) "Who Ends Up in the “Lake of Fire?”"
    }
    ["featured_image"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3355 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(86) "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
    }
    ["audio_file"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3350 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(84) "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2002mp3/188_Who_ends_up_in_the_lake_of_fire.mp3"
    }
    ["youtube_id"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3351 (0) {
    }
    ["open_par"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3346 (0) {
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3359 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "Doctrine"
    }
  }
  [7]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "156"
    ["title"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3348 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(37) "Is Jesus Really God? (Parts III & IV)"
    }
    ["featured_image"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3361 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(86) "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
    }
    ["audio_file"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3356 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(72) "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2001mp3/156_Is_Jesus_really_God.mp3"
    }
    ["youtube_id"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3357 (0) {
    }
    ["open_par"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3352 (0) {
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3365 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "Doctrine"
    }
  }
  [8]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "155"
    ["title"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3354 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(35) "Is Jesus Really God? (Parts I & II)"
    }
    ["featured_image"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3367 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(86) "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
    }
    ["audio_file"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3362 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(72) "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2001mp3/155_Is_Jesus_really_God.mp3"
    }
    ["youtube_id"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3363 (0) {
    }
    ["open_par"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3358 (0) {
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3371 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "Doctrine"
    }
  }
  [9]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "124"
    ["title"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3360 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(42) "Did God Really Create the World in 6 Days?"
    }
    ["featured_image"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3373 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(86) "http://www.christianquestions.net/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/cq_small_logo-310x227.jpg"
    }
    ["audio_file"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3368 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(96) "http://www.christianquestions.net/en/2000mp3/124_Did_God_create_the_world_in_6_days_10_22_00.mp3"
    }
    ["youtube_id"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3369 (0) {
    }
    ["open_par"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3364 (0) {
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3377 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "Doctrine"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check `$arrayItem[$i]['title']` (and all the other elements), it's most probably an array itself.

Comment: Can you add a var_dump of `$arrayItem`. Most likely your data is different than what you expect.

Comment: Seems like $arrayItem has 3 dimensions instead of 2 as you expect.

Comment: 'title'=>$arrayItem[$i]['title'][0] and so on

Comment: I have added var_dump in my question edit. I will try your tip @apoq.

Comment: can you provide print_r($data) result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in your var_dump, the title is not a string, but an object, causing this behavior. If you want json_encode to encode the value as a string, not as an object, make sure to give it a string, e.g. by casting the value:

```
        'title' => (string)($arrayItem[$i]['title']),
```

Edit: Note that String conversion is not always that simple. Just casting works in this case because we're dealing with SimpleXMLElement objects. If you have regular objects/arrays, you may need to use something more appropriate (e.g. `$myarray[0]`).

Comment: in that case 'title' will be a "Array" :)

Comment: and we'll receive "Array to string conversion" notice

Comment: @VaheShadunts: I just tested it with SimpleXMLElement objects (which is what OP is dealing with), and in that specific case, it seems to work. Edit: Since the answer got accepted, I'd assume OP tried it and it worked. I will specify that this does not work in all cases though.

Comment: Thanks Vahe Shadunts. It did the trick. I am getting correct JSON now. Thanks again for taking a look.